# How to find WindowRef of Apple Help Viewer application?

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

In my Carbon application upon display of Preference Panes, I have a link which when clicked opens up Apple Help Viewer.

The problem I am facing is the Help Viewer Window is behind my preference pane window.

I would like to keep the Help Viewer window on top of the Preference Pane.

Is there any way to get the WindowRef of the Help Viewer app so that I can use SendBehind API to send the help viewer behind the current window.

Thanks a lot

Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing; you say the problem is that the help viewer window is behind the preference pane window, but that you want to use SendBehind to send the help viewer behind the current window.  I'm guessing you meant to say that the help viewer is in front.  This is a common annoyance, and I don't think there is a solution.

As for the more specific question, no, you can't get a WindowRef for a window in another process.  It's in a different address space.

Comment: Thanks a lot. actually for me the help viewer is behind the preference pane, but I want to bring it infront of the preference pane.

Comment: That's strange.  I wrote a system preference pane that has a help book, and the help window comes up in front of the preference pane.

Answer (score 0):

The Help Viewer is in a different process, so SendBehind isn't going to help you. It sounds more like your preferences window is in the wrong layer. What window class are you using? Are you changing its window group or anything like that?